# How to make List view scroll one row at a time

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a custom listview by extending `BaseAdapter`. Each row has one image and occupies 50% of the listview height, thats way my listview at a time shows two rows.
What I want is, when I scroll slow or fast, no matter how slow or fast, the list view should scroll only one item and should not display a half row...

What I tried was to use `smoothScrollTo(int)` but it did not solve my problem. With smooth scrolling it will still jerk.

My target sdk version is 7.

Answer (score 1):

For go little by little:

```
mList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {}

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) 
            {                   
                mList.getRefreshableView().setSelection(mList.getRefreshableView().getFirstVisiblePosition()+1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel after reading your requirements that you might be better of customizing the view switcher, as the list view widget converts it self in to a bitmap while scrolling & it will not be easy to go down to the scroller class to change the way the list scrolls.

Comment: can u give me any example please

Comment: This might not be exactly what you need but you can edit this to get where you want to go. [View-flow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)

Comment: i tried using above and in that i used CircleFlowIndicator i was able to scroll it vertically but it is not what i expect it is scrolling alot;

Comment: Please explain what you mean by scrolling allot.

Comment: if i click it just 2 or three pxl on screen vertically it run out upward so quickly and than lost items appears and than again disappears

Comment: I am afraid cheeta you will have take a call now, do you want to stick to this approach where you seem to have made some progress & change some more code or look for a new solution. I think that you will never find something that exactly matches your requirements.

Comment: If it means anything, I think you should stick to this approach and push forward.

Comment: at last i am able do but without using any listview or gallery like widget i used ScrollView and i add rows in it by code.... i will post my code after it completes.